# Store problematic string in a variable and then correctly reference the variable?

Tags: powershell

I use the amazing command line tool [FZF](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf)

It offers the means to set its interface colours inline (Linux users get a config file, windows inline only):

```
Fzf --color=fg+:#00b4eb,bg+:#3d3c3c,hl:#0069fc,hl+:#0069fc --color=info:#80807e,prompt:#0069fc,pointer:#008ffc --color=marker:#008ffc,spinner:#454445,header:#353636
```

As you can  see its a long line. besides I would like to build different configurations for different contexts via variables/functions , much like splatting parameters.

So I tried:

```
$Style = "--color=fg+:#00b4eb,bg+:#3d3c3c,hl:#0069fc,hl+:#0069fc --color=info:#80807e,prompt:#0069fc,pointer:#008ffc --color=marker:#008ffc,spinner:#454445,header:#353636"

FZF $Style
```

I get this error:

```
invalid color specification: hl+:#0069fc --color=info:#80807e  
NativeCommandExitException: Program "FZFCommandLine.exe" ended with non-zero exit code: 2.
```

Even when I use a non expandable here string I get the same error:

```
$Conf = @'
--color=fg+:#00b4eb,bg+:#3d3c3c,hl:#0069fc,hl+:#0069fc --color=info:#80807e,prompt:#0069fc,pointer:#008ffc --color=marker:#008ffc,spinner:#454445,header:#353636
'@
```

I am trying to replicate the typical literal behaviour:

```
FZF --color=fg+:#00b4eb,bg+:#3d3c3c,hl:#0069fc,hl+:#0069fc --color=info:#80807e,prompt:#0069fc,pointer:#008ffc --color=marker:#008ffc,spinner:#454445,header:#353636
```

The part after `Fzf` is the part  giving me trouble.

Comment: All the examples in the github README uses `'...'` single-quotes around the arguments passed to `--color`, maybe try `Fzf --color='fg+:#00b4eb,bg+:#3d3c3c,hl:#0069fc,hl+:#0069fc' --color='info:#80807e,prompt:#0069fc,pointer:#008ffc' --color='marker:#008ffc,spinner:#454445,header:#353636'`

Comment: Hey I tried that, that didnt work, it pointed me in the right direction though. I had to use arrays and compartmentalise every `--color` call: ````"--color=fg+:#00b4eb,bg+:#3d3c3c,hl:#0069fc,hl+:#0069fc", "--color=info:#80807e,prompt:#0069fc,pointer:#008ffc", "--color=marker:#008ffc,spinner:#454445,header:#353636"
```` Thanks allot for hellping me with this!

Comment: Nice. Post an answer below! :)